Using Google Apps Script to create Bluesky Posts, and struggling to correctly configure Facets (mentions, links, hashtags)
I am using google apps script for a project that automatically posts to Bluesky.  It is correctly logging in and getting access.  It is correctly creating posts.  I have added in functionality to create replies by adding the reply block to the post, with the correct root and parent tags.  And I have it posting images correctly (most of the time; I still have issues recognizing when an image is too large, but that's a different problem).  Because all of that works, I will not include any of that code here.
Now I am trying to add in functionality to correctly indicate facets, like mentions, links, and hashtags.  Specifically, I'm look at hashtags right now.  I suspect if I can get this to work, I can get links and mentions to work as well.  However, despite multiple attempts, I'm not getting it to correctly format the hashtag.
I have logic in my script that recognizes that there is a hashtag present.  It then sends both the post text and the hashtag text (substring of the post) to a function that is supposed to be returning the starting and ending indices of the hashtag text, so that I can include that in the facet block.  Because Bluesky works in UTF-8 and apps script UTF-16, that function does some conversion, to get the UTF-8 indices.  I suspect that function could be where some of my problem is, but I'm not sure.
function getUtf8Indices(text, substring) {
  // 1. Convert the UTF-16 string to a byte array using UTF-8 encoding
  var byteArray = Utilities.newBlob(text, 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8').getBytes();

  // 2. Find the starting byte index of the substring
  var byteStartIndex = byteArray.indexOf(Utilities.newBlob(substring, 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8').getBytes()[0]);

  // 3. Calculate the ending byte index
  var byteEndIndex = byteStartIndex + Utilities.newBlob(substring, 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8').getBytes().length - 1; 

  return { byteStart: byteStartIndex, byteEnd: byteEndIndex };
}

That function is called within my block to create the post initially.  Here is the section specific to the facet / hashtag process.
if(iRow[7] != "" && iRow[7] != null) {  //is there a hashtag value?
    var indeces = getUtf8Indices(iRow[3], iRow[7])  //pass the whole post & the hashtag value (substring of the post text) to get the start / end indices of the substring
    this.facets = [
      {
        index: {
          byteStart: indeces.byteStart,
          byteEnd: indeces.byteEnd,
        },
        features: [{
          $type: 'app.bsky.richtext.facet#tag',
          tag: iRow[7].replace(/^#/, ''),
        }]
      }
    ]
  }

It does return the indices, and when I Log the characters at the start / end indices, it does identify the start / end of the hashtag string.  But then when the post is created on Bluesky, it's not formatted as a hashtag (string shaded blue), but just as plain text.
Here is the postObject from a test post:
{facets=[{features=[{tag=TestPost, $type=app.bsky.richtext.facet#tag}], index={byteStart=46.0, byteEnd=54.0}}], repo=did:plc:{my did}, record={$type=app.bsky.feed.post, createdAt=2024-12-26T15:41:33Z, text=This is a post to test the hashtag function.  #TestPost}, collection=app.bsky.feed.post}

And here is the resulting post:

I suspect a couple different options.

I could be missing something really obvious; a typo that I'm just overlooking for example.  Or maybe I'm not sending the correct substring (I've done it both with and without the '#' as part of the substring, and that doesn't seem to make a difference).
Or it could be something in the getUtf8Indices() function.  Full disclosure, I didn't write that function, but copied it from somewhere, so it's entirely possible that isn't actually doing what I need it to do.
Or it could be something else entirely.

I've tried a bunch of different things, and nothing has worked.  Any suggestions or guidance would be great.

According to Wikipedia, Bluesky is a microblogging social media service. Similar to Twitter, users can share short text messages, images, and videos in short posts colloquially known as "skeets". It is owned by Bluesky Social PBC, a public benefit corporation based in the United States.

But then when the post is created on Bluesky, it's not formatted as a hashtag (string shaded blue), but just as plain text. Would you please edit the question to provide a sample of a post to BlueSky, and an example of the respective Bluesky post.
